# How to make a bluetooth connection between Android Phone and PC without knowing server UUIDs?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I am making an app to sync my PC and Phone together with bluetooth when they are paired. Since I want to be able to use multiple devices, I want to generate unique UUIDs to identify each phone/computer in the mix. However, according to the [Android Doc pages](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices), if I want to connect to a device, I need its UUID. Is there some way to connect hard coding in a UUID? Can I create a server connection just based on the mac address of the device?

Comment: When the Bluetooth is scanning you will get the identifiers, based on that you exposed them to the UI

Comment: you might be able to put the UUID in the advertising packet. Is this Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth classic?

Comment: @cutiko How can I get the appropriate UUID though? I know how to get the address and the name from a connected device, but not the bluetooth UUID.

Comment: @Marc I know how I can advertise the server on the desktop end, but I'm unsure how to get the UUID from it without already being connected to it. Do you know how?

Comment: In the section "Connect as a client" the same you are referencing, there is literally a link to the documentation on how to scan for devices, the link says: Find Bluetooth devices. Click that.